# A lot of routes in one module.exports

Tags: node.js

```
// app.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

let jsonController = require("./jsonController.js");

app.get("/readJson", jsonController);

app.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log("Listening");
});
```

```
// jsonController.js
module.exports = () => {
    < --- here --- >
};
```

Can I find out in `<--- here --->` from route it was called?

Something like this:

```
// jsonController.js
module.exports = () => {
    if called from "/readJson" {
        (res, req) =>  {
            res.send("FROM READJSON"); }
        }
};
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is **`req.route.path`**.

If controller is configured as `app.get("/readJson", jsonController);` and `app.get("/readJson2", jsonController);`, then in `jsonController`, you can get how it is called by:

```
// jsonController.js
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  let routePath = req.route.path;
  if (routePath === '/readJson') {
    res.send('From readJson');
  } else if (routePath === '/readJson2') {
    res.send('From readJson2');
  }
};
```